# what does it mean to have multiple equal signs on the same line?

Tags: javascript

what does this line of code mean below? is it some some sort of ternary operation?

```
this.object01 = object02.attribute01 === someString;
```

this is using aurelia javascript

Answer (score 3):

Break it down. There's two operations going on here: an assignment statement (one equals sign) and an equality check (three equals sign) which returns a boolean.

`this.object01` is now a boolean containing `true` or `false` depending if `object02.attribute01 === someString`.